# Should I call a single sql statement to retrieve data for a service or different distinct calls

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have a requirement where I need to return some data from a web service (in .net). The response of the service would be a class having different attributes. Some of the attributes are complex and need data to be fetched for such types need separate call.
Ex:

```
Class getServiceData

{

    public int SimpleProperty1 {get;set;}

    public int SimpleProperty2 {get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<ComplexProperty> {get;set;}
  ...

}
```

For getting the data for such class, I need to call the Oracle database. My question is whether I should bring all the data for the service in a single sql statement (please note the structure involves some hierarchy) or call separate statements for different attributes of the class.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hierarchical queries done by the client involve probably many roundtrips between the application-code and the server. (at least if you do not use PSQL)

Since oracle is perfectly capable to handle hierarchical queries in one statement, **I recommend to use that feature**. It is much more performant, imO does not put more load onto the server than multiple regular queries and produces the same results.

The downsides I see, are

1. if you use some mapping library you might need to use native statements and therefore drop the support of the framework.
2. the query might be complex and not easily understandable for people who later have to maintain your code.
3. The code is not easily portable to other databases, if you decide to switch. Since the oracle hierarchical (connect by prior) feature came quite early on the market,  it has not so much in common with recursive CTE-queries, other dbms support.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is the biggest criteria, then I would ask you to pull all the data in a single query itself.

Using Oracle to directly return data is easier than using any wrapper that would return data in parts.

However be careful if you are using a Stored Procedure with a lot of processing in it as this can become difficult to debug and has the tendency to become a black box while testing (hides the processing from code).